# .net core project.json test-scoped dependencies

Tags: unit-testing, scope, nunit, .net-core, project.json

So I basically want to be able to have a test-only dependency that is available during dotnet test. Is there a way to do it?

I am aware that project.json is scheduled to be sunsetted, but until that time, I will continue to use it.

Comment: project.json is already deprecated, VS2017 and associated tooling was released 6 days ago.

Comment: dotnet test --configuration "Test-only" then nest "dependencies" under "configurations" or under "compilationOptions" set a "define" constant (untested ideas).

Comment: Couldn't you put that dependency in your test project?